# Help me set NumLock on external keyboard different from internal laptop keyboard

Tags: keyboard, numlock

I have an Entroware laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 installed.

I have attached an external logitech wireless mouse and keyboard set through a USB port. Now, whenever I change the NumLock status on the external keyboard, also the internal one is affected and vice versa.

I don't want this to happen. Specifically, I want to set the NumLock ON on the external keyboard, and OFF on the internal one.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: It's working as designed.

Comment: Maybe, but I would like it to work differently, if possible.

Comment: It is not......

Comment: This really needs to happen, some how, some way. I don't care if it takes a third party utility. Most laptop keyboards overlay their numeric pad on the letter keys, so when NUM LOCK is on, the letters type numbers instead (making it useless for general typing); however, when connecting an **external** keyboard with a dedicated numpad, it's helpful to have NUM LOCK on to be able to use the pad. Why has no one written something to do this? I would if I could :(

Comment: You could try using xinput as noted here: https://superuser.com/a/648480

Comment: On some thinkpads this could be configured inside the BIOS to keep numlocks in sync (or not).